Getting Error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] String data, right truncation and Dates sorting incorectly
I am accessing a SQL database and pulling data that I will then filter further for a variety of uses. The current version which pulls properly includes a date column showing YYYY-MM-DD and I want it to be MM-DD-YYYY. Additionally, I am seeking to add a filter field by setting two parameters to cells within the Excel workbook. When those cells are changed, the data pulled will be within the bounds of those parameters.
I have been able to get the dates to show correctly MM-DD-YYYY, but they do not sort in order, it has Jan 2024 dates before Oct 2023 dates.
When I add the filter fields using between ? & ? I get the String Data right truncation error from the title here.
This is my date formatting command line
Select(Format( Cast( vwAccountTransWithPO_Mod."TRX Date" AS Date), 'd', 'en-US')
Why would this cause sorting issues and how do I fix this?
This is my custom filter command
Where(vwAccountTransWithPO_Mod."TRX Date" between ? & ?)
I have used this with a similar report and not received this error, I am not sure what the issue is.

Sort on the original true date value, not the formatted text.
